# Как называется элемент управления, который на картинке? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Как называется элемент управления, который на картинке и если это ListView, то подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать также?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разве не обычная таблица?

Comment: @Tode Дело в том, что Хедеры(название столбцов) находятся слева, мне бы хотелось добиться такого же эффекта.

Comment: а это точно связанно с C# ?

Comment: @pavel1787mego Да c# - .NET-совместимый язык.

Comment: @Tode Просто было круто реализовать такой же на WPF

Comment: То, что на картинке, обычно propertygrid  называется. Частный случай таблицы.

Comment: Это окно свойств!

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо, но можете приблизительно объяснить как такое создать?

Comment: @Tode Как это понять?

Comment: Зависит от того, что у вас. Если вам нужно подобие окна свойств (есть объект со свойствами "страна", "год", "жанр") то просто возьмите готовый контрол - гугл в помощь.

Comment: `WPF` на то и `WPF`, что такой элемент можно собрать кучей разных способов. Это может быть `Grid`, может `StackPanel`, `ItemsControl` или `ListBox`... или еще что-то другое

Comment: @Андрей Тоже верно, ладно буду делать StackPanel в котором множество ListBlock'ов получается, что так.

Comment: я не думаю, что вам нужно использовать какой-либо элемент управления, скорее подойдет обычный `Grid`, а внутри несколько `TextBlock`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="text1 in header  " Background="Gray"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="text:" Background="Gray"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="text:" Background="Gray"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="text2 in header" Background="Gray"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="editable text"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="editable text"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!Это то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home

Элемент управления PropertyGrid позволяет проверять и редактировать свойства объекта. Этот PropertyGrid позволяет автогенерировать все свойства или указать конкретные свойства, которые вы хотите отобразить. Вы можете использовать стандартные редакторы, которые предоставляются с PropertyGrid, или вы можете использовать настраиваемые редакторы, которые нацелены на тип, конкретные свойства или и то, и другое. PropertyGrid также поддерживает сложные свойства, что позволяет вам развернуть иерархию вложенных свойств.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, разве что один вопрос, этого элемента нет среди стандартных, как его подключить?